# Restrict Access to Products Based on Role WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles

I am currently attempting to prevent users from being able to see products and categories based on their role on my WordPress site with WooCommerce. Is there a recommended plug-in or change in the code I can implement to solve this issue?

Background: This site sells products (wholesale/retail). Users with increased privilege are able to purchase certain items that retail users/visitors will not be able to see.

I have been able to accomplish the effect where the items are hidden using the plugin Booster: Product Visibility by User Role; however, the categories with their respective pictures still appear and results are still counted.

Are there any other suggested plugins that accomplish this? Or is there an option in Booster that I am missing?

Thank you for your help in advance. :)

[image: Hidden Products Producing Results using the Booster Plugin]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the user role and display appropriate content like this:

```
<?php if( current_user_can('editor') ) : 
    // display content for editors
endif ?>
```

Comment: I'll check that out now. Thank you for the response, if it works I'll be sure to mark it.

Comment: Yes please, let us know.